# Is it possible to use a query result into another query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I have two queries that I want to combine, the first one returns a document with some fields.
Now I want to use one of these fields into the new query without creating two separates ones.
Is there a way to combine them in order to accomplish my task?

This is the first query

```
{
"_source": {
    "includes": [
        "data.session"
    ]
},
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "field1": "9419"
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "field2": "5387"
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "time_zone": "+00:00",
                        "gte": "2020-10-24 10:16",
                        "lte": "2020-10-24 11:16"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"size" : 1
```

}

And this is the response returned:

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 109,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.4183793,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "file",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "UBYCkgsEzLKoXh",
            "_score": 3.4183793,
            "_source": {
                "data": {
                    "session": "123456789"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I want to use that "data.session" into another query, instead of rewriting the value of the field by passing the result of the first query.

```
{
"_source": {
    "includes": [
        "data.session"
    ]
},
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "data.session": "123456789"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"sort": [
    {
        "timestamp": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use the result of the first query as an input to the second query, then it's not possible in Elasticsearch. But if you share your query and use-case, we might suggest you better way.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch does not allow sub queries or inner queries.